# how to get cell value Datagrid EasyUI PHP clicked

Tags: datagrid, cell, click

can somebody help me how to get selected cell value when I click cell of Datagrid ? wondering I have datagrid with 5 fields and many rows, but I want to get cell value from datagrid which I clicked the row. Thanks advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you need get row's value use this :

```
var row = $('#datagrid').datagrid('getSelected');
```

If you need get cell's value use this :

```
$('#datagrid').datagrid({'onClickCell': function (index, field, value) {
   .... your code ...
}});
```

Answer (score 0):

first you need to set datagrid property with `onClickRow: onClickRow,`
and then you can add this function

```
function onClickRow(index){
  var tr = $(this).closest('tr.datagrid-row');
  var idx = parseInt(tr.attr('datagrid-row-index'));
  var ed = $("#dg").datagrid("getEditor", {index:editIndex, field:'myfield'});
  var value = $(ed.target).val();
}
```

value variable will fill with the value from myfield when the row is click

Hope this can help you